# Accessing a table by name in Word using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a document containing lots of tables. I want to modify those tables using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I read that I can iterate trough all tables using the Tables interface.

Question: is it possible to give the table a name/ID and access the table by its name? (like with shapes in Powerpoint automation).

Question 2: If it's not possible with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, do the alternatives like Aspose Words offer a more convenient way?

Comment: Does the Name or ID need to persist with the document? For example, closing/reopening? If so, this will significantly change the nature of the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to give the table a name/ID and access the table by its name?

The Table object does offer an [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.id.aspx) property however this is only documents saved as a web page. I am assuming this is not what you want.

It is still possible however it is not provided by the API; you need to create this feature yourself. There are two ways:

**One:** Using Interop, you can retrieve the table's hashcode which (hopefully) returns a unique ID. For example:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\HasTables.docx");
var tableID = wordDoc.Tables[1].GetHashCode();
```

A thorough solution might be to store the IDs of all tables in the document within a Dictionary or another collection type which has a map of key/value pairs. Now note that these IDs do not persist across Word sessions...so if you need to be able to identify a table beyond the same session, you will need to another method.

**Two:** Using OpenXML (for .docx format) and/or WordML (for Word 2003 XML, if you cannot simply upgrade the ocument to .docx) create your own Id or Name attribute for each w:tbl element. You can disambiguate by using your own namespace. This will also persist across Word sessions. This is a different world then Interop, but in my opinion, is the much better route (Performance, available documentation).

> If it's not possible with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, do the alternatives like Aspose Words offer a more convenient way?

No, Aspose does not offer anything like this in their [TableCollection](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/TableCollection+Members) or [Table](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Table+Members) objects.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I'll have a closer look at the OpenXML format as the IDs should persist with the document. I have to check now if it is possible to determine the height of a given table cell when using OpenXML (what I do is: open a given document, do  lots of find/replace operations and measure the height of the resulting cells).

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010, a new table property was added called Descr which is intended for a table description, but can be used as a Name field as well.  You still need to loop thru the Tables collection to find the one you need, but it does give you a way to tag a table with something that persists after saving and reopening the table.