# Removing empty table cells from Word document using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, docx

I have created a CV maker with Novacode docX which replaces text on a template and then saves it. The issue i have is with the employment history which i have done in a table for formatting purposes. There is no set amount of employment history records, thus i had to create a maximum amount of 10 record templates for this. My code works fine to replace the records, however i then get blank table cells which does not look good at the end of the document. Is there any way i can remove these empty table cells from the generated CV ?

Is it possible to maybe give the table a  title and find the empty cells in that table and remove it ?

My code - this is the replace text code which i use after i get the data from my database table

```
            'if there is data it replaces it as such
            document.ReplaceText("#employername1#", "NAME OF EMPLOYER")
            document.ReplaceText("#dates1#", "DATES OF EMPLOYMENT")
            document.ReplaceText("#position1#", "POSITION")
            document.ReplaceText("#reason1#", "REASON FOR LEAVING")
            document.ReplaceText("#jd1#", "JOB DESCRIPTION")
            document.ReplaceText("#skills1#", "ACHIEVEMENTS")


            document.ReplaceText("#empdata1#", employer)
            document.ReplaceText("#datedata1#", employmentsd & " to " & employmented)
            document.ReplaceText("#posdata1#", position)
            document.ReplaceText("#reasondata1#", reasonleave)
            document.ReplaceText("#jddata1#", jobdesc)
            document.ReplaceText("#skilldata1#", achievements)

        Else
            'if there is no data it replaces it with a blank(which is why i need to remove these blank cells)
            document.ReplaceText("#employername1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#dates1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#position1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#reason1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#jd1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#skills1#", "")

            document.ReplaceText("#empdata1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#datedata1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#posdata1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#reasondata1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#jddata1#", "")
            document.ReplaceText("#skilldata1#", "")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code to understand the problem better.

Comment: try this solution if you want to access table in one session: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116266/1498401, if you want to persist marking of your table across sessions you can try using bookmarks to access specific range by name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/bookmarks-object-word

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have amended my post to include my code snippet